# VERY New to VB2010, trying to create button that opens form to read/edit app.config

Tags: vb.net

extremely new to VB2010. I am working with a very simple database in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am trying to build a form that has a button on it that will open up a 2nd form that allows me to view and edit the connection string. I believe the connection string is also called app.config, and can see that in the Solution Explorer for the project.

All I have managed to do is drag a button onto my main form and relabel it. I have no idea how to create code to access the connection string.

Any help that points me in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2):

- [Getting Started with Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466159)
- [Learning Visual Basic from the Ground Up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789086)
- [Visual Basic 2008 / 2010 Tutorials](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/)
- [Visual Basic Developer Centre](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789056)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is what i did... might not be the best way, but it works.

No need to use another form.
In the toolbox add a Panel (located under the "Containers" group),
Then stretch it over your form.
In the Panel's Properties section,
Set its Name (lets say "config") and set Visible to False.

Then when you want to display the config panel, add this in your code

`Me.config.Show()`

Then put a button on the panel and use

`Me.config.Hide()`

when you want to close it.

Also you probably want to save these settings for another session, check out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8.aspx

I know this is a late but i hope it helps someone if you have already figured anther way!